# Using Operator += in C# value

Tags: c#, operators

I'm trying to use "+=" to increase "int Pos" in Secondclass by 1 for each time i run the for loop. But it's not working as well as the one i did in the static void main.

Here is my code:

```
namespace Newbie
{
public class Firstclass {
    int Pos = 1;
    int Neg = 0;
    public void Method1(string str) {
        if (Pos > Neg)
        {
            Secondclass obj = new Secondclass();
            obj.Pos += 1;
            obj.Method2();
        }
    }
}
public class Secondclass {
    public int Pos = 0;
    public int Neg = 0;
    public void Method2() {
        if (Pos > Neg) { 
            Console.WriteLine("Pos = {0}", Pos); 
    Console.WriteLine(); 
        } else { Console.WriteLine("fail"); }
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        for (; ; ) {
            string e = Console.ReadLine();
            Firstclass objj = new Firstclass();
            objj.Method1(e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? it's behavior is right if you want to increase Pos prop of second class in `for` loop you should use public variable but each time you are instantiating `obj` of `SecondClass` then `Pos` initiating with zero and just be 1 each time.

Comment: Now, it is just always 1. I want it to be 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does exactly what is expected - displays
Pos = 1
every time you hit enter.

If you expect to see

Pos = 1

Pos = 2

Pos = 3

...

you should make following changes to Firstclass and Main

Good luck with studying c# :)

```
public class Firstclass
{
    int Pos = 1;
    int Neg = 0;
    Secondclass obj = new Secondclass();    //    this should be here
    public void Method1(string str)
    {
        if (Pos > Neg)
        {
            //Secondclass obj = new Secondclass(); -- you shouldn't create new object any time Method1 is called
            obj.Pos += 1;
            obj.Method2();
        }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Firstclass objj = new Firstclass();    //    this should be here
        for (; ; )
        {
            string e = Console.ReadLine();
            //Firstclass objj = new Firstclass(); -- you shouldn't create new object on every iteration
            objj.Method1(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Theair you should mark it as the correct answer ;)